# get value in array object with big data

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object

I want to get value in object if this exist in my array. 
The data is too big that why I want the fast method to get it. 
my array containt more than 4000 object. 
What do you suggest to me to use: simple loop, foreach, ... ?

I want to get boolean value in values array in MY_GOAL_1 object if it exists.

```
 {
  "extensionId": "  ",
  "version": "001",
  "features": [
    .....
    .....
    {
      "logicalKey": "MY_GOAL_1",
      "featureLabel": "Option Selected",
      "typeCode": "BOOL",
      "groupCode": "TOT",
      "groupId": "*",
      "isDisabled": false,
      "isRequired": false,
      "values": [
        {
          "value": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "logicalKey": "MY_GOAL_2",
      "featureLabel": "Option Selected",
      "typeCode": "BOOL",
      "groupCode": "TOT",
      "groupId": "*",
      "isDisabled": false,
      "isRequired": false,
      "values": [
        {
          "value": false
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you pls tell your expected output?

Comment: i want to get this boolean: "values": [
        {
          "value": false
        }

Comment: I think your output should be "values":  [ { "value": true } ],  no? given your above object for "MY_GOAL_1"

Comment: I have added an answer for this. You can check if this is what is expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for this. Below I have used subset from your object.

```js
var obj = {
  "extensionId": "  ",
  "version": "001",
  "features": [
    {
      "logicalKey": "MY_GOAL_1",
      "featureLabel": "Option Selected",
      "typeCode": "BOOL",
      "groupCode": "TOT",
      "groupId": "*",
      "isDisabled": false,
      "isRequired": false,
      "values": [
        {
          "value": true
        }
      ]
    }
]
}
var foundObj = obj['features'].find(d => d.logicalKey == "MY_GOAL_1")
var result = foundObj && foundObj['values']
console.log(result || 'not found')
```